# Parse string by more values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot parse string in Python. I need to parse it by specifics words. I write pattern how my string loooks bellow. I need to parse it by categories ("Description: ....." , "Return code: ....." , etc.), which can have more than one row of text. Do someone please know how to change my code or some advice?

I have string in this format:

/***********************************************************************
 * Name            :  some_text 
 * Preconditions   :  some_text 
 * Parameters      :  some_text 
 *                    some_text 
 *                    some_text 
 * Return code     :  none 
 * Description     :  some_text 
 **********************************************************************

I tried standart split in python, but I am not sure how to use it so output will be list of parsed categories. If I want to parse it by "\n" it works, but as I mentioned, category can have more than one row.

```py
ReturnCodeName = tmpTextString.split("Return code     :")
DescriptionName = tmpTextString.split("Description     :")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use regular expressions to solve this problem:

```
import re

input_str = '''/***********************************************************************
* Name : some_text
* Preconditions : some_text
* Parameters : some_text
* some_text
* some_text
* Return code : none
* Description : some_text
**********************************************************************'''
pattern = '\* Name : (.*)\n'

print(re.findall(pattern, input_str))
```

That returns:

```
['some_text']
```

A more generic solution to find all the parameters would be:

```
import re

input_str = '''/***********************************************************************
* Name : some_text
* Preconditions : some_text
* Parameters : some_text
* some_text
* some_text
* Return code : none
* Description : some_text
**********************************************************************'''
pattern = '\*[ ]+(.*)[ ]+:[ ]+(.*)\n'

print(re.findall(pattern, input_str))
```

That returns:

```
[('Name', 'some_text'), ('Preconditions', 'some_text'), ('Parameters', 'some_text'), ('Return code', 'none'), ('Description', 'some_text')]
```

To understand better how regular expressions works I suggest this website: https://regexr.com/

**EDIT:**

Edited the last code to include multi line parameters:

```
import re

input_str = '''/***********************************************************************
* Name : some_text
* Preconditions : some_text
* Parameters : some_text
* some_text
* some_text
* Return code : none
* Description : some_text
**********************************************************************'''
pattern = '[ ]+(.*)[ ]+:[ ]+([^:]*\n)'

print(re.findall(pattern, input_str))
```

That returns:

```
[('Name', 'some_text\n'), ('Preconditions', 'some_text\n'), ('Parameters', 'some_text\n* some_text\n* some_text\n'), ('Return code', 'none\n'), ('Description', 'some_text\n')]
```

Comment: Sorry, my answer does not include the multi line parameters. I will try to find a fix and edit it

Comment: I tried 
textParts = re.compile("[\w\s]+\s\:").split(tmpTextString)
which works, but I need to check results if it work on everytime.

Comment: I edited it. Now it accepts every character (including new lines) except for ":" and makes sure that the final character is always a new line. I couldn't think of a case it wouldn't work. If will want to remove the '*', I would suggest just replace it after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would have done it, base on the string format you have.

First I would split the text by `\n` so I'll get each line separately. Then if after splitting by `' : '` I'm getting an array of length 2 (meaning there is a left side and right side to the `:`), I'm putting it inside `object`, as a key value pair, where the key is the property (after getting rid of the `'* '` at the start), and the value is the right side of `:`.

It looks like this:

```
hugeString = '''
* Name : some_text 
* Preconditions : some_text 
* Parameters : some_text 
* some_text 
* some_text 
* Return code : none 
* Description : some_text
'''

arr = hugeString.split('\n')

object = {}
for a in arr:
    splitted = a.split(' : ')
    if len(splitted) == 2:
        object[splitted[0][2:]] = splitted[1]

print object['Return code']
print object['Description']
```